# Display Custom Post Type Category

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

I have set up a Custom Post Type called "tours" with a Taxomony "tour_category" Specific only to that Post Type. Inside the Taxomony I have set up 4 areas Golf Breaks, Walking Tours etc... What I am trying to achieve is render all the Posts in the Golf Breaks Taxomony into the golf.twig template however all I seem to get is a page not found error. Can someone point me in the right direction with this example.

```
$context = Timber::get_context();
$args = array(
// Get post type tours
    'post_type' => 'tours',
// Get all posts
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
// get post in "Golf Breaks" category
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'tour_category',
            'value' => 'Golf Breaks',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    ),
// Order by post date
    'orderby' => array(
        'date' => 'DESC'
    ));

$context['Golf Breaks'] = Timber::get_posts( $args );

Timber::render( 'golf.twig', $context );
```

Comment: If you're getting a 404 it is likely that this code isn't even running.  This sounds like it might be a more general Wordpress error.  Have you rebuilt the permalinks since you created the "tour_category"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@richard: you're going to have a very bad time with this line....

```
$context['Golf Breaks'] = Timber::get_posts( $args );
```

Since the property of the array is used by Twig, you want something with no spaces (and probably lowercase). Try....

```
$context['golf_breaks'] = Timber::get_posts( $args );
```

from there you can access the data in Twig with...

```
{% for post in golf_breaks %}
    <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
    <div>{{ post.content }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

If you're not seeing anything, the problem is likely with fetching the posts from WP. Things with taxonomy queires can be tough, try debugging with just a `get_posts` to ensure WordPress is finding posts that match yr query